# PIGPIO Stream Incoming Data with a timestamp and in Hex to a Laptop with USB

Tags: raspbian, pigpio

i use the Raspberry Pi 2 Model B and want use the Raspberry as a Man-in-the-middle.

description what i want to do:
I have to catch the incoming data (9-bit protocol 4800 baud) transform them to hexadecimal and set a timestamp for every databyte. Then i want to send the data as stream over USB to my Laptop. on my laptop i must see the datasteam in realtime.

I have experimenting with the Pigio library but i didn´t find an opportunity
to catch the datasteam after the incoming bit´s were transformed into bytes is that possible?
Is it possible to convert the byte´s into hexadecimal not decimal?
And is it possible to set a timestemp to every byte in microseconds at the beginn of the recording?
So that i finally send a datastream e.g. timestamp hexbyte timestamp hexbyte...
over the USB to the laptop.

I hope someone can help me and i say thanks ahead

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to write your own code to meet those requirements.

pigpio will read the serial data and place it into a buffer.  It does not time-stamp each data byte.

Apart from that requirement the rest you can do with pigpio and is just a standard programming exercise (with the possible exception of USB to laptop as it is not clear what you mean by that).

Comment: Ok thanks then i write my own software Uart for my projekt.

Comment: @sniffi To work it will probably have to be based upon pigpio.  If I were you I'd just modify pigpio's bit bang serial receive routine to save a time-stamp for each 9-bit byte.

Comment: Ok i will try it. I already have wrote now my own Software Uart which set a timestamp im microseconds per byte. I synchronize the datasteam at every startbyte(zero) i hope that works. Now i must lock how can i take the incoming datasteam an give them over a data inputstream into my Uart. When that works i must look how can i steam the datasteam into my laptop over USB or ethernet.